# authTimeout in Yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-user

I am trying to log out user automatically in `yii2` after he is idle for a fixed seconds  .
In `web.php` I added

```
'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'app\models\User',
            'enableAutoLogin' => true,
            'authTimeout'=>100
        ],
```

inside `components` . I am using basic template. But it is not logging out automatically. Does this work in Yii2? I was following documentation from http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-user.html

Comment: Do you expect completely automatic logout? I think it will happen only if user was unactive for this amount of time and then tries to open / refresh certain page.

Comment: i want the user to be redireted to site/login

Comment: I asked about details of that. Custom javascript is needed in order to achieve complete automatic logout. See @Pavel Bariev's answer.

Comment: then what difference the value for authTimeout brings to the system?

Answer (score 4):

`$authTimeout` - public property.

The number of seconds in which the user will be logged out automatically if he remains inactive. If this property is not set, the user will be logged out after the current session expires (c.f. `yii\web\Session::$timeout`).

Note that this will not work if `$enableAutoLogin` is `true`.

Answer (score 1):

Your config is correct. But it will not automatically refresh your page and show you login form. Technically it will log you out only at the next request after the session is expired. And you should be aware of ajax scripts working on your page and calling some other pages by time interval. Every request will renew your session timeout.
There is also "absoluteAuthTimeout" parameter instead of "authTimeout" - that will log you out after the timeout despite of your activity.

Comment: but it is not working . I tried absoluteAuthTimeout also

Comment: This is exactly what I want to specify / explain in my comment. The user didn't provide details about that.

Answer (score 0):

In your `config/web.php` file:

In `$config` array:

...

```
'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'app\models\User',
            //'enableAutoLogin' => true,
            'enableSession' => true,
            'authTimeout' => 60,
        ],
```

...

Please note I commented the `//enableAutoLogin`, that prevents of `authTimeout` to work properly

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
session.gc_maxlifetime
```

setting in php.ini

By default it is 1440 secs.

Answer (score 0):

if you want log out user after X time. You should check with ajax each second. If expired redirect to log out

Comment: I also implemented this functionality by this method only

Answer (score 0):

Just remove "enableAutoLogin" from your user config and it will just work fine.

Your code shall look like this:

```
'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'app\models\User',
            'authTimeout'=>100
        ],
```