# How to change time for stay in login (dekturim users)

Tags: yii2, yii2-user, yii2-extension

I want to change the time of stay in login in my site. How can I change it?

I founded `$authTimeout` for this issue but I can't use that!

This is my config of `web.php`:

```
'modules' => [
    'user' => [
        'class' => 'dektrium\user\Module',
        'controllerMap' => [
            'admin' => 'app\controllers\user\AdminController',
            'security' => 'app\controllers\user\SecurityController',
            'registration' => 'app\controllers\user\RegistrationController'
        ],
    ],
],
```

this is example for my problem but i dont know use from that : https://github.com/dektrium/yii2-user/pull/801/commits/bdc27d60e76017276751c4eb3a9b2257bc204708

Comment: why cant you use that ($authTimeout)?

Comment: Where should I put this?($authTimeout)

Comment: Did u see that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30523110/5867369 ?

Comment: Setting unknown property: dektrium\user\Module::authTimeout